# Wordpress template file author.php. How to get author ID?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Question is about Wordpress template file author.php.

At author.php, I need to output author ID, to get more info, but I cant do that. Maybe someone can help ?
Example:
http://www.domain.com/?author=1
Need to output Author ID: 1

http://www.domain.com/?author=2
Need to output Author ID 2

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Setting Up for Author Information](http://codex.wordpress.org/Author_Templates#Setting_Up_for_Author_Information) section of the Author Templates section of the codex.  Once you've initialised `$curauth` you should be able to use `$curauth->ID`.